# Create a Grunt Plugin that embeds other Grunt Plugins

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm creating a grunt plugin and I'd like to use other existing grunt plugins.

I.e. I'd like to embed existing grunt plugins withing my created plugin.

Looking in the code of existing plugins this scenario doesn't seem to be pursued.

Is that scenario have been thought by the Grunt devs?

What would be the right way to implement such embeding?

Comment: What does "embedding a plugin in a plugin" mean?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by "embedding" other tasks?

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't do that, its way too bad practice from my point of view, you could try instead to declare as dependencies in `package.json` , and later work inside your plugin, by requiring and exporting tasks or whatever your plugin does.